# How to groupby columns from two dataframes and then apply aggregate difference function between rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes as follows:

```
+--------+----------+------+-------------------+
|readerId|locationId|userId|          timestamp|
+--------+----------+------+-------------------+
|      R2|        l1|    u2|2018-04-12 05:00:00|
|      R1|        l1|    u1|2018-04-12 05:00:00|
|      R3|        l3|    u3|2018-04-12 05:00:00|
+--------+----------+------+-------------------+

+--------+----------+------+-------------------+
|readerId|locationId|userId|          timestamp|
+--------+----------+------+-------------------+
|      R1|        l1|    u1|2018-04-12 07:00:00|
|      R2|        l1|    u2|2018-04-12 10:00:00|
|      R3|        l3|    u3|2018-04-12 07:00:00|
+--------+----------+------+-------------------+
```

I want to group `readerId` and `locationId`, then find the timestamp difference for the grouped values. For example: For readerID `R1`, locationID `l1`, the timestamp difference is 2 hrs.

I implemented it by joining the two dataframes and using `withColumn`.

```
val joinedDf = asKuduDf.join(
        asOutToInDf,
        col("kdf.locationId") <=> col("outInDf.locationId") &&
          (col("kdf.readerId") <=> col("outInDf.readerId")),
        "inner")
      //Time loged in calculation
      val timestampDf = joinedDf.withColumn(
        "totalTime",
        ((unix_timestamp($"outInDf.timestamp") -
          unix_timestamp($"kdf.timestamp"))/60).cast("long")
      ).toDF()
```

Is there a better way to do this? I also tried following way.

```
val unionDf = outToInDf.union(kuduDf)
val timeDiffDf = unionDf.groupBy($"readerId", $"locationId").agg(diff($"timestamp"))
```

But the problem with the above approach is that there is no 'diff' function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` is the right solution here. In general `GROUP BY` with aggregation is not an option, especially if (`readerId`, `locationId`) are not unique identifiers.

You could

```
unionDf
  .groupBy($"readerId", $"locationId")
  .agg((max($"timestamp").cast("long") - min($"timestamp").cast(long) / 60).alias("diff"))
```

but this is highly artificial solution and doesn't offer any advantages over `join`. It is also sensitive to some subtle data issue.

Comment: While you're correct about the `join` being the correct solution here, I think you have to assume the `(readerId, locationId)` pair to be unique, otherwise the whole problem makes no sense, whether one uses aggregation or join - as what would be the meaning of the difference, when there's several values on each side?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two dataframes with `union` and in the aggregation, you can calculate the difference as

```
val mergedDF = asKuduDf.union(asOutToInDf)
  .groupBy($"readerId", $"locationId")
  .agg(collect_list($"timestamp").as("time"))

mergedDF.withColumn("dif",
  abs(unix_timestamp($"time" (0)) - unix_timestamp($"time" (1))) / 60
)
```

Output:

```
+--------+----------+------------------------------------------+-----+
|readerId|locationId|time                                      |dif  |
+--------+----------+------------------------------------------+-----+
|R3      |l3        |[2018-04-12 05:00:00, 2018-04-12 07:00:00]|120.0|
|R2      |l1        |[2018-04-12 05:00:00, 2018-04-12 10:00:00]|300.0|
|R1      |l1        |[2018-04-12 05:00:00, 2018-04-12 07:00:00]|120.0|
+--------+----------+------------------------------------------+-----+
```

Hope this helps!